# Meta$^{n{-}th}$ mathematics

Tags: lo.logic, mathematical-philosophy, metamathematics

Metamathematics has a reasonably clear connotation,
enough to have [a Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamathematics),
with Gödel, Tarski, and Turing playing leading roles;
Kleene's book (*Introduction to Metamathematics* ([Amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0923891579)));
Chaitin's article ("[Meta-mathematics and the foundations of mathematics.](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~chaitin/italy.html)" *EATCS Bulletin*, June 2002, vol. 77, pp. 167-179); etc.
My question is:

> **Q**. Is there an identifiable ***meta***-metamathematics, a scholarly study of metamathemaics,
>   perhaps in the philosophical (rather than mathematical) literature?
>   Or does all the literature essentially "devolve" to metamathemathics,
>   without an identifiable line that can be drawn between metamathematics and
>   meta-metamathematics?

Citations to possibly-meta-metamathematical studies would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This might be a naive question but don't metamathematical theorems, once you formalize them, become mathematical and therefore meta-metamathematical theorems are simply metamathematical? For example, you can prove theorems like "the theory T proves that the theory S proves...etc.", which you might consider meta-meta-meta-...-mathematical, but isn't this just metamathematics?

Comment: @Burak: I would say that it is difficult to maintain the position that, say, Gödel's incompleteness theorems are just theorems of mathematics.

Comment: @Joseph O'Rourke: Eventhough I would like to agree with that, I cannot see how to make the distinction precise. Say, for example, you are doing your Gödel numbering in such a way that sentences starting with $\exists$ are always assigned to even numbers. Is the statement "there exist infinitely many even numbers" a metamathematical fact? It tells you that there exist infinitely many sentences starting with $\exists$. But it also tells you that, well, there are infinitely many even numbers.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be asked on the meta site? :-)

Comment: @Asaf I agree with your comment, but doesn't it belong on the meta-meta-site?

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen: Thanks for that reference---I agree that I unwittingly nearly duplicated that recent question, which has informative responses.

Comment: @Andreas: I believe this was discussed before; on the StackExchange network, the meta operator is idempotent.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke:  Is the four-color theorem "just a theorem of mathematics?"  Is the Pythagorean theorem "just a theorem of mathematics"?  Is there some relevant sense in which these differ from Godel's theorems?

Comment: Metamathematics is really mathematics (of mathematics, or more precisely certain formalizations of it), and the meta is just a (useful) linguistic device to help us distinguish the investigation from the object being investigated. This precaution is peculiar to logic, and indeed we need not call the investigation of groups meta-group-theory (but we could): one only rarely mistakes a proof of Lagrange's theorem for a group.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

My opinion is that there is no crisp distinction between
mathematics, metamathematics and meta-metamathematics, and the
subjects thoroughly blend one into another in such a way that
prevents any coherent distinction.

Furthermore, even the categorization of particular topics as
mathematics or metamathematics has changed radically over time,
and many topics that were formerly considered metamathematics are
now just mathematics. For example, the ultrapower construction was
born in metamathematics, but is now widely seen as a fundamental
mathematical construction. The method of forcing was initially
used only for relative consistency proofs, but is now saturated
with a mixture of infinite combinatorics, ideals, Boolean
algebras, topology, transfinite limits, and so on. Computability
theory was born in purely philosophical speculation about what it
means for a human to undertake a computable procedure, but gave
birth to complexity theory and other extremely applied
mathematical topics. Is the polynomial time
hierarchy regarded today as metamathematics? I don't think so, but
it is a part of complexity theory, which is a part of
computability theory, which is traditionally considered
metamathematics. The study of large cardinals is tied to
fundamental issues in logic, such as definability and
constructiblity, but also involves at its core essentially
mathematical questions about infinite combinatorics, measure
theory, complex systems of embeddings and so on. Where does the
mathematics end and the metamathematics begin? It is all wrapped
up together.

The term metamathematics has traditionally included the entire
subjects of model theory, set theory, proof theory and
computability theory, but I think this kind of usage of the term
is simply no longer accurate, since huge parts of these subjects
are now more mathematical than metamathematical. I think that the
term "metamathematics" may have made more sense as a unifying
umbrella term in an earlier age, when many mathematicians were
simply less familiar with these subjects than is the case today.

Consider my work with Benedikt Löwe on [the modal logic of forcing](http://jdh.hamkins.org/themodallogicofforcing/). The main theorem is that
the ZFC provably valid principles of forcing are exactly those in
the modal theory known as S4.2. Now, the principles under
consideration, the principles of forcing, can themselves surely
be considered as metamathematical, as they concern how truth varies in the generic
multiverse, the Kripke model of possible worlds consisting of the
set-theoretic universe in the context of all its forcing
extensions. Since the principles are thus metamathematics, and we are
proving theorems about which principles are provably valid, one could consider this to be solidly a case of meta-metamathematics. But if
you look at the paper, I think you will mainly find just plain old
mathematics, with detailed inductions and finite partial order
combinatorics and some infinite combinatorics and forcing
iterations, mixed in with some modal logic, which is essentially finite combinatorics. This example therefore illustrates my point that there
is really no coherent distinction into
mathematics/metamathematics/meta-metamathematics.

Comment: I have learned a great deal from this and the other responses and comments---Thanks!

Comment: It is clear that there are mathematical statements that are not metamathematical and vice versa.  For example, the statement `ZFC is consistent' is purely metamathematical, while its translation Con(ZFC) via Godel numbering is a mathematical (in fact, arithmetical) statement.  Is not the distinction a valid and useful one?

Comment: @JesseElliott I believe that the distinction is not as clear as your remark suggests. For example, I believe that many people would say that both of those statements are meta-mathematical, and others would say that those are the same statement, with the same meaning, even though they are said differently.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. Con(ZFC) is a (probably true) statement to the effect that a certain complicated Diophantine equation has no integer solutions, expressed as a statement of PA. `ZFC is consistent' is the metamathematical statement that ZFC is consistent.  They happen to be equivalent.  Con(ZFC) is actually many statements, since it depends on what Godel numbering assignment you choose.  So if they are all the same statement, then you are implying that all of the Diophantine equations you can get by different Godel number assignments are all identical, which is definitely not the case.

Answer (score 8):

This is has been considered in philosophy perhaps even more so than mathematical logic.  I would consider Lindstroem's theorem (roughly, first order logic is the strongest system in some sense for which one can have a compactness theorem and a downard Lowenheim-Skolem theorem) as a result in meta-meta-mathematics, because it talks about several systems of possible logics and provides an interesting result.  Beyond that level may be distinctions that can be appreciated by practitioners,  but from my non-professional and non-philosophical perspective, it is a form of hair-splitting to be practiced by people other than me.  I don't see how higher levels will benefit my or anyone elses studies, and I've done more than an average amount of reading in mathematical logic.